# WMI remote installation(python script) 1619 Error

Tags: python, windows-installer, wmi

import wmi

```
connection = wmi.connect_server (
  server="myserver",
  user="putilalala",
  password="ololo"
)
c = wmi.WMI(wmi=connection)

result = c.Win32_Product.Install(
    PackageLocation="\\\\mypc\\tmp\\python-3.4.1.msi",
    AllUsers=True
)
print( result)
```

I got 1619 error: installation not found"
It's work only with local(myserver) folders: PackageLocation="c:\tmp\python-3.4.1.msi"
Is it possible to install MSI file from UNC location?

Comment: according to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/891753/en-us
"This path is relative to the computer on which the software is being installed and which can be referenced by using a Universal Naming Convention (UNC) path" Does myserver has access to `\\mypc\tmp\python-3.4.1.msi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works only with local path or unc on local path...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install from UNC shares, but that error is the Windows Installer "cannot open file", so my guess is that it's a local configuration or security issue accessing the file.

Quote:

ERROR_INSTALL_PACKAGE_
 OPEN_FAILED             1619   This installation package could not be 
                                opened. Verify that the package exists and 
                                that you can access it, or contact the 
                                application vendor to verify that this is 
                                a valid Windows Installer package.

Comment: I test it, I have full access to shared folder.